# connecting graphics card to PSU

Tags: power-supply, gpu

I'm trying to connect a 3070 ti Founders Edition to a Thermaltake Toughpower GF1 Series 750W 80 PLUS GOLD power supply. The GPU has a 12-pin connection and came with a dual adaptor that connects the 12-pin to 2 8-pins. My problem is that I only have 1 free 8-pin coming from the PSU. there are several others unused (a few 4-pins, for example). Can I simply buy an 8-pin connecter, remove one of the extra 4-pins from the back of the PSU and attach the 2nd 8-pin of the nVidia adaptor to the PSU with the new cable?

Or is there something easier I'm missing completely?

Comment: " Can I simply buy an 8-pin connecter, remove one of the extra 4-pins from the back of the PSU" - No

Comment: Your PSU should have more than one PCI-E 8 pin slot available. What are the other ones doing?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments of OP, there is no way to plug in an additional 8-pin cable to the back of the power supply. **AND** there was indeed a 2nd 8-pin slot/cable. I was thrown off because for my PSU, that 2nd 8-pin is split on the other end in to 2 x 6+2s... so when I was searching through the rats nest, i was looking for a straight 8-pin on the other end.

So now I'm connecting the 1st 8-pin from the 1st port and **ONE** of the 6+2s from the 2nd 8-pin to the dual 8-pin to single 12-pin adapter that plugs into my 3070 Ti.

It looks something like this:

```
    8-pin ------- 8-pin -> 8-pin ---------\
   /                                       \
PSU                                         -----> 12-pin -> GPU
   \               6+2-pin -> 8-pin -------/
    8-pin ------- /
                  \
                   6+2-pin
```

All is good. Thanks for the guidance in comments above.